# My bad vs. Our bad

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

Has anyone one of you heard the phrase in the plural form? I'm about to translate a rap song :D and I don't really want to say 'we're sorry' there. 'My bad' would be a perfect fit, but the thing is this is a group of people whose 'bad' that is. So, is it a thing, 'our bad', and if it's not, maybe you've got some other suggestions?

Comment: Could you add two or three surrounding verses to contextualize the question? Especially when translating, the context can often be more useful that simply considering the exact translation/definition alone.

Answer (score 3):

If my friend and I ruined your birthday party by showing up late, I could aptly speak for the both of us and say, "Our bad." That wouldn't be weird sounding. That would be totally understood. People pluralize "my bad" as "our bad" all the time.

Here's an example of it being used by [Apple](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/436-oops-our-bad/id394775318?i=1000519252475) for the name of an Apple podcast:

> "Oops, Our Bad"

Here's an example of [CapitalOne](https://ficoforums.myfico.com/t5/Credit-Card-Applications/Capital-One-SavorOne-quot-Oops-our-bad-quot/td-p/6039164) using it to apologize to customers for a technical problem they'd been experiencing:

> "Oops, our bad!"

Here's an example of [Grinnell College](https://magazine.grinnell.edu/news/oops-our-bad) apologizing for a mishandling of votes in a piece it published in *The Grinnell Magazine*, titling the piece:

> "Oops! Our Bad"

To be clear, saying "oops" is ***not*** a prerequisite for saying "our bad," just like it's not for saying "my bad." It's just that I know from personal experience "oops" often accompanies "my bad" and "our bad," and since Boolean searches don't allow for the use of punctuation, punctuation after "our bad" (e.g., "Our bad.") being the only other way I could think of to find examples of it, I figured plugging "oops" in before "our bad" in Google was the best way for me to find real examples of "our bad" being used to claim blame, as opposed to "our bad" being used as a modifying phrase before a noun (e.g., "our bad relationship"), which resulted in so many hits that I needed to filter them out in order to readily find examples of "our bad" being used to claim blame.